# Start transfer learning on a saved keras Inception v3 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a trained Keras Inception v3 model named 'nsfw.299x299.h5' that I downloaded from Github.
Github Link: https://github.com/GantMan/nsfw_model
This model classifies the images into the following 5 categories:

1. Neutral
2. Porn
3. Hentai
4. Sexy
5. Drawing

The model is giving False Positives on some coffee cup images and classifying them as "**Porn**" when it should have been classified as "**Neutral**".
So to remove the bias, I downloaded some 400 images of COFFEE CUPS and downloaded the same number of images for other classes as well, and want to train this model again.
How do I proceed with the training?

Below are the last few lines of a summary of the model.

```
 __________________________________________________________________________________________________
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================        
                    

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_94 (Activation)      (None, 8, 8, 192)    0           batch_normalization_94[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mixed10 (Concatenate)           (None, 8, 8, 2048)   0           activation_86[0][0]              
                                                                 mixed9_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 concatenate_2[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_94[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_10 (AveragePo (None, 1, 1, 2048)   0           mixed10[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 2048)         0           average_pooling2d_10[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          524544      flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 256)          0           dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          32896       dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 128)          0           dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 5)            645         dropout_3[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 22,360,869
Trainable params: 17,076,261
Non-trainable params: 5,284,608
```

The code that was used for the training of this model is given below that I took from the same Github repo which I downloaded the model from: https://github.com/GantMan/nsfw_model/blob/master/tf1/training/inceptionv3_transfer/train_initialization.py

```
conv_base = InceptionV3(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False, 
    input_shape=(height, width, constants.NUM_CHANNELS)
)

# First time run, no unlocking
conv_base.trainable = False

# Let's see it
print('Summary')
print(conv_base.summary())

# Let's construct that top layer replacement
x = conv_base.output
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8))(x)
x - Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(seed=None), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(.0005))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
# Essential to have another layer for better accuracy
x = Dense(128,activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(seed=None))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
predictions = Dense(constants.NUM_CLASSES,  kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation='softmax')(x)

print('Stacking New Layers')
model = Model(inputs = conv_base.input, outputs=predictions)

# Load checkpoint if one is found
if os.path.exists(weights_file):
        print ("loading ", weights_file)
        model.load_weights(weights_file)

# Get all model callbacks
callbacks_list = callbacks.make_callbacks(weights_file)

print('Compile model')
# originally adam, but research says SGD with scheduler
# opt = Adam(lr=0.001, amsgrad=True)
opt = SGD(momentum=.9)
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Get training/validation data via generators
train_generator, validation_generator = generators.create_generators(height, width)

print('Start training!')
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    callbacks=callbacks_list,
    epochs=constants.TOTAL_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=constants.STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    shuffle=True,
    workers=4,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=constants.VALIDATION_STEPS
)

# Save it for later
print('Saving Model')
model.save("nsfw." + str(width) + "x" + str(height) + ".h5")
```

Comment: what do you want excatly? do you want classify new images?

Comment: I had some NEUTRAL images of COFFEE CUPS that were being classified as PORN instead of NEUTRAL. So to remove the bias from the model, I collected some images of COFFEE CUPS and collected the same number of images for all the other classes. In conclusion, I want to remove the bias from this model for COFFEE CUP images.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples, I spend a bit of time on the similar method using image_genertor and fit_genertor which will obsolete soon as in return messages.

About your question, to retrain this model with CIFAR_10 or CIFAR_100 you can use pip install cifar10 or cifar100. Alternatively, you can create your own dataset using a dataset or data generator: below is a sample using standard dataset CIFAR-10.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_generator.fit(x_train)

history = model.fit( train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, subset='training'), epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=1 )
    
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

plt.show()
plt.close()
    
input('...')
...
```

For extract CIFAR you can do as follows:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSets
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset_cat = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("F:\\datasets\\downloads\\PetImages\\train\\Cat\\*.png")
dataset_len = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset_cat).numpy()
list_label_cat = [0 for i in range(dataset_len)]
list_image = []

for elem in dataset.take(10):
    element_as_string = str(elem.numpy()).split('\'')
    image = plt.imread(os.fspath(element_as_string[1]))
    list_image.append(image)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_image, list_label))
dataset = dataset.batch(10)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sw6.png)